# Apply SLA based on case priority

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

We have requirement where high priority case are considered to be served 24*7 but the cases with Normal or Low priority are to be served only during 9 AM to 6 PM. I have configure multiple SLA items in single SLA for Normal and Low priority. But business hours are defined at SLA level, how can i differentiate that?

I found similar question but no answer. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution by creating a plugin that sets Calendar according to Priority of the created case. In case anyone is suffering from the same thing !